# gksudo equivalent for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sudo, root, gksudo

Is there a gksudo equivalent (or Cpp / Qml api call) that lets you ask for a password in a graphical way on Ubuntu Touch?

Thanks